# Indexing in Apache Solr of all files contained in a folder and its subfolders

Tags: indexing, solr

Can Apache Solr be used to index all the files of a folder(Parent) and its subfolders, containing files of  all types:  XML, .json, .pdf,.doc etc..?

Answer (score 2):

Using post tool can be done

`java -Dc=test -Drecursive -Dauto -jar post.jar folder`

-Dauto for all file types that solr can handle

-Dc to specify collection name

-Drecursive to handle if folder has files inside subfolder.

if folder has has subfolder it will index files inside subfolder

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Data Import Handler to achieve that . You can find information about how to implement it here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler . Data import handler has an option recursive=true that allows you to index files nested in folders .Go through documentation in the link , and you will find a solution for yourself . Hope this helps :) .

Answer (score 0):

Latest Solr actually ships with an examples showing how to do that, including a custom interface to play with. The example is located in **examples/files** and you just need to follow the **README.txt** instructions.