# how to index txt files in folder in windows with solr 7.7.2 in java api?

Tags: java, indexing, solr

**How can i Index a large number of *.txt files in a folder in windows whit apache Solr 7.7.2 in java api ?**

following code

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/test_core";
SolrClient Solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
...
...
...
others
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249343/indexing-in-apache-solr-of-all-files-contained-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders

Comment: https://blog.webnersolutions.com/apache-solr-indexing-all-files-in-a-folder-recursively/